# Is the expression "What's that mean" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, sentence

Today I saw a comic where one of the characters say:

> What's that mean?

[image: Link to the comic]

I am not a native English speaker but that sentence puzzled me.

I would personally use the verb `to do` here but instead there's a `'s` which I assume is the verb `to be` contracted.

The other option is that `'s` here is the verb `to do` contracted, but I'm not aware of this contraction to be possible.

Is the sentence correct in English? Or is it some "slang" language.
The character is not supposed to speak slang or incorrect English at all, so that's why this sentence drew my attention.

Comment: What does that mean? I do, you do, he/she/it does. It’s a contraction of "does", I think.

Comment: Can "does" be contracted as 's? I'm not aware of that contraction. Is it correct English? Is it common to contract "does" like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“What's that mean?” is a very informal contraction, typical of speech, of the following

> [What is that supposed to mean?](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/what-s-that-supposed-to-mean)

From *Macmillan Dictionary*

> used when you are annoyed or offended by something that someone has just said
>
> - A: *‘I just assumed you wouldn’t know.’
>
>   B: ‘Well, what’s that supposed to mean?’*

Comment: Or possibly a swallowed syllable from the pair of t/d sounds in "What does (that mean?)".

Comment: @Lawrence s'pose that's true true as well :)

Comment: Haha :) . (Too bad there aren't emoticons in upvotes.)